# UIObjects returning nil in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, appdelegate

I have a problem using `UIView` (Named “DateTimeView”) & `UIDatePicker` (Named “pcvDateTime”) in `AppDelegate` because it returning `nil` to both UIObjects.

I’m using `CustomIOS7AlertView` add-on ([There Site](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)) in `didReceiveLocalNotification:` , and I’m using the add-on to add a UIView in AlertView and it worked in to places in app but in `AppDelegate` it didn’t work because The UIObjects returning `nil`.

views.xib :

[image]

AppDelegate.h :

[image]

AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomIOS7AlertView.h"

@synthesize window, DateTimeView, pcvDateTime;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
CustomIOS7AlertView *DateTimeAlert;
DateTimeAlert = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];
                pcvDateTime.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
                [pcvDateTime setDate:[NSDate date]];
                [DateTimeAlert setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cancel", @"Set Alarm", nil]];
                [DateTimeAlert setContainerView:DateTimeView];
                [DateTimeAlert setDelegate:self];
                [DateTimeAlert show];
}
```

% Not the full code just what important % , here is problem, the `AlertView` showed but its empty body and when i used break point it showed me that the UIObjects are `nil`, any answer?

Comment: Why are you initializing `DateTimeAlert` twice?

Comment: Remove the `DateTimeAlert = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];` after `[pcvDateTime setDate:[NSDate date]];`

Comment: Deleted, but still need an answer to my problem. PLS working 3 days and can't solved it.

Comment: Why are you doing anything like this in the app delegate? Just don't. Stay out of there unless it's something that the app delegate is built to do (like, being a delegate for the application).

Comment: because i want to use `didReceiveLocalNotification:` to set an snooze using DatePicker